# Make the dropdown menu of bootstrap at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the dropdown menu component of twitter/bootstrap

And i have a timer countdown 10 minutes

I want to make dropdown menu show up (at top), and won't vanish even if user click the other place.

Only after user hovered that dropdown list, user can let it vanish by click other lace.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="/account" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User Name</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="first" id = "mymenu">
    <a href="/users/edit">setting</a>
    </li>
        <li class="last">
            <a href="/users/sign_out">sign_out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

How can i do that?

I had though about use event handler to prevent vanish even, but how can i do that?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: I have notice that twitter/bootstrap use css to show/hide dropdown menu...

Comment: Did you find the solution for your problem? I'm looking the same question=) If you solved this, could you post your answer, please

Comment: It can be solve by add css class which display is block, and when timeout add this class to dropdown-menu. Meanwhile, add mouseenter event at it to cancle this class.

Comment: But finally i didnt use this way to my ui, it just appear by .toggle()